# Is it possible to run RAPIDS on Debian?

Tags: debian-based, rapids

I wanted to try RAPIDS but I have seen that it is only compatible with Ubuntu 16.04/18.04 and CentOS 7.
Since I have already a completely operational Debian 9 system installed on my workstation, and since I know Ubuntu is a Debian derived distro, I was wondering if it is possible to run it on Debian following Ubuntu instructions.
Thanks in advance for your help

Guido

Answer (score 2):

RAPIDS really has only two dependencies: CUDA and CONDA. As long as you get full support for CUDA 9.2, 10.0, or 10.1 on your Debian distro, and anaconda, you should be able to use RAPIDS.